# How does the browser resolve the relative location of './'?

Tags: html, url, browser, relative-path

I am combining many small semi-static, single-page webapps into one larger web site. The backend is a lot of proxies, but the forward facing server basically just make it look like the app was moved from the root filepath to a more specifics one. IE:

```
/
├── css
│   └── app1.css
├── index.html
└── js
    └── app1.js
```

would be moved to

```
/apps/app1/
├── css
│   └── app1.css
├── index.html
└── js
    └── app1.js
```

This migration has been relatively painless mainly due to the use of `./` in the apps' html files, such that **most** apps just load their resources relative to their new location. The problem I am having is that some apps are resolving `./` differently. For these trouble cases, the primary html file gets loaded; however, the `./` in the `script` and `style` elements are resolving to a higher file-path (IE: I would expect `./` to resolve to `/apps/app1` but am getting `/apps`). It may be a coincidence, but the troubled apps often have additional, non-index HTML files.

What are the rules for how `./` is resolved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Determine the base URL

   - This is usually the URL of the HTML document
   - It might be overridden by the [`base` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base)
   - For CSS it is the URL of the stylesheet

     - JS is always with respect to the HTML document
2. Remove everything **after** the last `/` in the *path* section of the URL

   - e.g. the base URL for `https://example.com/example/foo?bar=baz#fragment` is `https://example.com/example/`
   - Keep in mind that an HTML document might be visible at the path `/example` and `/example/` and you should avoid this by making one path canonical (I prefer the one that ends in a `/`) and redirecting to it from the other
3. Strip the `./` from the front of the relative path
4. Append the result of step 3 to the result of step 2

---

A common gotcha is to confuse URLs with file paths. While a simple static site will usually have a direct 1:1 mapping between them, many modern sites will use routing code (e.g. [for Express](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/basic-routing.html) for HTML documents and a separate [static route](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html) for static files like images, js and css.

Comment: I think the trailing `/` the is cause of the behavior. Thank you for the thorough response!